# RHEL 6.0 enterprise intallation probelm on hp gen8 server

Tags: raid, rhel6, controller

i am unable to install rhel 6 enterprise edition on hp dl380p gen8 server. with a p420i raid controller with 512 mb cache.
whenever i boot from my media.. after asking for language and keyboard type.. it say NO DRIVER FOUND.

assist me what to do and how to do it .

Comment: at exactly what point does it say this, you need to provide a LOT more information.

Comment: What media version are you actually using?

Comment: add some screens maybe, more info

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using the newest ISO? 

The RHEL 6.2, 6.3 and 6.4 installation media works fine on HP ProLiant Gen8 servers.

Answer (score 0):

with server HP you mast have CD with drivers(supplement pack), and you can use supplement pack for rhel.

more info in supplement docs on site HP 
http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/doc/p1822529277/v81556/RHEL6.3SPPSupplement2012.06.0BReleaseNotes.pdf